# Shopify - Change opacity sold out product's thumbnail

Tags: javascript, java, e-commerce, shopify, product

I would like to have an opacity applied to the thumbnail when an article is sold out, is it possible?

```
<div class="product-details">
  {% if settings.display_vendor %}
    <span itemprop="brand" class="brand">{{ product.vendor }}</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</span>

  {% if collection_handles contains 'coming-soon' %}
    <span class="modal_price">{{ 'collections.general.coming_soon' | t }}</span>
  {% else %}
    <span class="price {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}sale{% endif %}">
      {% if product.available %}
        {% if product.price_varies and product.price_min > 0 %}
          <small><em>{{ 'products.general.from' | t }}</em></small>
        {% endif %}
          {% if product.price_min > 0 %}
            <span class="money">{{ product.price_min | money }}</span>
          {% else %}
            {{ settings.free_price_text }}
          {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        <span class="sold_out">UH OH, WE’RE OUT</span>
      {% endif %}
      {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
        <span class="was_price">
          <span class="money">{{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }}</span>
        </span>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if settings.enable_shopify_collection_badges and settings.enable_shopify_review_comments %}
    <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You might need to add a class `sold-out` (or anything) to the `product-wrap` div to be able to style your image

Comment: Thanks for your comment @t3__rry I was wrong to publish the generated html code, now I put the original. I would need to apply a function that says when the price of the product is sold_out an opacity is applied to the thumb. Does this make sense?

Comment: you seem to show the sold out message if not `product.available` so why not add a class when not `product.available` for your opacity